# Recoding unix command ls in c (formatting output)

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm recoding the Unix command ls, im using multiple system functions including but not limited to , ,  functions etc. I have all the information I need and have already taken big strides. However, I need help with formatting the output.

when you run the command ls -l and the output is formatted so all columns are the right size regardless of the length of said files names.

I would like to know how to format my output in the same manner as ls, with regard to columns (Just a general idea not actual code). How do I do this?

Comment: How would you format it by hand on a piece of paper ? You can also consult the documentation of printf.

Comment: Go through this [https://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output]. You'll get a good idea how to do that.

Comment: In C there are format specifier which can be specified in `printf` functions.

Comment: thanks , really helpful.

Comment: Why are you using the `ls` command - read up about [opendir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir), [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) etc. and use them instead

Comment: im using opendir and readdir to code a ls type function @EdHeal

Comment: @afullstopdot - Please clarify the question to include this

Comment: Prepare an array of file names to be printed. Find out max length. Add some padding. Decide what page width you want. Divide said page width by said max length. That's your number of columns. Print each filename to same field width equal to said max length.

Comment: The information you need is in `man 3 printf`. Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %, and ends with a conversion specifier. *In between there may be* (in this order) *zero or more flags, an optional minimum field width, an optional precision and an optional length modifier*. You can for example, with filenames, etc., find the longest name `max` and then specify the *minimum field width* within the format specifier of `"%-*s ... ", max, str, ..."` (preceded by the `-` left justify flag) to format strings and similar with integer and float types.

Comment: thank you very much @DavidC.Rankin that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are various non-printing escape characters that can perform tasks such as moving the cursor to a specific location, changing the font and background colors, etc. You can use them to move the cursor to calculated positions to achieve the neat column-based formatting like the output of the `ls` command. The characters you would want to consider are the following:

- `\033[l;cH`: Moves the cursor to line *l* and column *c*.
- `\033[nA`: Moves the cursor up *n* lines.
- `\033[bB`: Moves the cursor down *n* lines.
- `\033[nC`: Moves the cursor forward *n* characters.
- `\033[nD`: Moves the cursor backward *n* characters.
- `\033[2J`: Clears the screen and moves the cursor to line 0 and column 0
- `\033[K` : Without moving the cursor, clear the line starting from the current cursor position.
- `\033[s` : Store the current cursor position
- `\033[u` : Move the cursor back to the previously stored location.

For example, the following statement moves the cursor to the the top-left corner of the screen and clears the first line, and returns the cursor back to its original location.

`printf("\033[s\033[0;0H\033[K\033[u");`